# Changing font of CSS

Tags: font-face

I downloaded a .woff font from fontsquirrel.com. Inside the CSS that they provided along with the .woff file, two important lines

```
font-family: 'walkway_boldregular';
src: url('walkway_bold-webfont.woff')

I'm trying to change a font of another CSS and it shows that

font-family: 'Raleway';
src: local('Raleway Thin'), 
local('Raleway-Thin'), 
url('raleway100.woff') format('woff');
```

My question is, what would the lines then look like if I implemented Walkway font constricting to the format of Raleway?